# Flutter: How to catch "Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)"

Tags: flutter, dart, clipboard

I have a text field where I can paste text. I  use this to paste URL's from the internet.
If I accidentally paste a large chunk of code from my clipboard instead of normal text or URL's, it gives me the following error:
**Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)**.

How can I catch this error so that the user has a good experience?

---

### [EDIT]

There is a button with a clipboard icon that the user can tap. Here is where the error happens once this button is tapped by the user:

```
onTap: () async {
    if (linkTextController.text.trim() == "") {
        try {
            ClipboardData? data = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
            linkTextController.text = data!.text.toString();
        } catch (error) {
            print(error);
        }
    } else {
        linkTextController.text = "";
    }
    setState(() {});
},
```

Comment: This is a `FormatException`. Can get detailed idea if you could put some sample code.
try to handle exception in whatever funtion you are doing above task.

Comment: @vat69 I have added a code sample. Hope it helps!

Comment: You are calling `Uri.parse` somewhere.  Put that in a `try` block and catch the `FormatExeption`, or [`Uri.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/tryParse.html) instead.  If you don't know where you're calling `Uri.parse`, then look at your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the `onChanged` event of the `TextField` using [official document - Handle changes to a text field](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes)

**UPDATE**

You might want to use `hasStrings()` first, [given here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html), because the official documentation for [ClipboardData class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/ClipboardData-class.html) clearly states that:<br /

> The system clipboard can contain data of various media types. This data structure currently supports only plain text data, in the text property.

Comment: the error seems to happen before on changed is called. I have tested by adding a print function and triggering the error. The error appears before the onChange can be triggered.

Comment: check answer, see if it helps